# CSS3 Animation - typing effect

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking for a solution for a "typing effect" animation for a list of text.

Examples of a great typing effect plugin [@Paulund](https://twitter.com/paulund)

http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/typing-effect/

```css
.css-typing
{
    width: 30em;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-animation: type 5s steps(50, end);
    animation: type 5s steps(50, end);
}

@keyframes type{
    from { width: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type{
    from { width: 0; }
}
```

```html
<p>We offer<span class="css-typing">Item 1 to Item 3</span> at low cost prices</p>
```

How would I get it to loop through a list of items to type out? Note: I want the previous item to disappear, so only 1 item at a time.

We offer **.....** at low cost prices

Replace **....** with the following and wrote in a typing effect, looping through them.

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4

Comment: Are the list items dynamic or static?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just use the plugin? That's kind of what it does. http://jsfiddle.net/9pzcbv3t/

Answer (score 0):

Here Span tag not working you can use another tag.

```css
.offer{
    width: 100%;
display: block;
float: left;
list-style:none;
}
li {
float: left;
width: 100%;
}
p {
float: left;
}
.css {
width: 46px;
/* float: left; */
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
-moz-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-moz-animation-name: slidein;
-webkit-animation-name: slidein;
}

@-moz-keyframes slidein {
  from {

width:1px;
  }
  
  to {

width:46px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
  from {
   
width:1px;
  }
  
  to {

width:46px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="offer">
<li><p> We offer:</p><p class="css">Item 1</p><p> at low cost prices</p></li>
<li><p> We offer:</p><p class="css">Item 1</p><p> at low cost prices</p></li>
 <li><p> We offer:</p><p class="css">Item 1</p> <p>at low cost prices</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe OP wants to loop the items item1 to item3 and not the text `item1 to item3`

Comment: My code supporting animation now OP can use it in his loop without using span tag

Comment: In question animation was not working so I solved animation problem.